# Flipped CollectionView in UICollectionViewController is covered by Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

In the picture below, I am flipping the collectionView using :

```
   collectionView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI))
```

[image]

; and the reason I am doing that is to make pagination easier. But the problem I am having is in the picture below, I am scrolled all the way to the top... but the navigation controller is covering my collectionview. However before it was flipped the text would be right under it.

Also If i scroll all the way to the bottom you can see that the navigation padding was switched the bottom.

[image]

I'm really not sure how to fix this, as the padding is automatically generated, is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the property `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` on UIViewController, which automatically adds an inset on scroll views so their content can scroll under opaque bars without covering the initial content. Since your scroll view is rotated 180 degrees, you will need to turn this off and manually apply the correct insets for your rotated view controller.

You might find Slack's chat view controller useful as it provides an example implementation that scrolls from the bottom up: https://github.com/slackhq/SlackTextViewController